# How to fill form fields having same class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, clojure

I am testing a website form using clj-webdriver. I want to know how to use `(input-text)` function if the form fields have same class.

From the `(input-text)` definition it gives "Type the string `s` into the first form element found with query `q`". Since every field has same class and when I give,

```
(input-text ".class")
```

It only fills the first field. Is there any way to differentiate all fields with the same class?

The fields of the form has only `class` and `type` as selectors.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`input-text`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#input-text) only fills the first match.

Use [`quick-fill`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#quick-fill) to fill them all.

E.g.,:

```
(quick-fill {".class" "s"})
```

/edit

You say "for 2 fields of same class I have to enter 2 and 3 as values. and also if the class is "object object-done" can I consider class as ".object". I am not exactly sure what you mean with the latter, but what I understand is that you want to add different values to different elements.

If you want to find specific elements you can use [`find-elements`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#find-elements). These will return a collection of [elements](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Element-API):

```
(find-elements {:class ".class"})
```

This will find all elements with the class ".class" in order which they appear on the page.

If the collection is stored in a variable text can be added to every element via `input-text` based on index. So for example if you want to add an increasing index to them you can use [`map-indexed`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed) to add the index of every value to the element as follows (`doall` is called to walk every element in the lazy sequence - function calls are only made when the elements are accessed and [`doall`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall) makes that happen):

```
(defn fill!
  "Fills all elements with class class with increasing numbers."
  [class]
  (let [elements (find-elements {:class class})]
    (doall
     (map-indexed (fn [index element]
                    (input-text element (str index)))
                  elements))))
```

This function is called like `(fill! ".class")`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give example for 2 fields. :)

Comment: I mean for 2 fields of same class I have to enter 2 and 3 as values. and also if the class is "object object-done" can I consider class as ".object"

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a great help :)

Comment: And for the latter one, I meant if the class= "object object-done" How should I consider class as in quick-fill

Comment: It would be great help if you can tell me how to select radio buttons for a query

Comment: Thanks. If you want to find an object with a double class I think you can just use two class CSS-selectors, as in `(quick-fill {".object .object-done" "s"})` (note the dots, in CSS a dot prefix is used for selection of a HTML class and the # prefix for an HTML id). Radio buttons can be found with `(find-element {:tag :radio})`. See the great https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation. See the [elements API](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Element-API) for actions on elements. Selecting a radio button is calling the `select` action on the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `(find-elements [webelement by])` function, which returns a list of 'webelements`matching a given`by`.

From the project documentation, that can be found at https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Introduction%3A-Taxi , an example is:

```
(defn css-finder
  "Given a CSS query `q`, return a lazy seq of the elements found by calling `find-elements` with `by-css`. If `q` is an `Element`, it is returned unchanged."
  [q]
  (if (element? q)
    q
    (core/find-elements *driver* {:css q})))
```

Comment: I am actually just learning how to test. Its been only 2days. I have no idea what driver is and can you explain a little more. Sorry for the trouble.. but thanks

Comment: Certainly. A driver (actually WebDriver) is what Selenium uses to _drive_ or interact with the browser being used for the test. See [the documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) for more details.

Comment: What namespaces and dependencies should I have to use for driver. I am using clj web driver taxi